Problem of style files in flutter projects
I'm wondering if using style files with methods like these makes sense:
static TextStyle defaultStyle() {
  return const TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
    letterSpacing: 0,
  );
}

static TextStyle display1() {
  return defaultStyle().copyWith(
    color: AppColors.black900,
    fontSize: 57.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
  );
}

We keep these values in one place, but when using them, we can't use const before the widgets.
Result:
Text(
      'Hello',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: AppTextStyles.display1().copyWith(color: AppColors.gray500),
    ),

Instead of:
  const Text(
      'Hello',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
        letterSpacing: 0,
        color: AppColors.black900,
        fontSize: 57.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
      ),
    ),

I've noticed this in every project I've watched so far. Isn't this a mistake that affects the performance of the application?

Well, it isn't a mistake. It does have it's own effect on performance but they are so small and almost non-existent.
One reason why many opt-in for this sort of implementation is to avoid repetitive-coding, a situation where you repeat something you have used implemented somewhere in your code before. Imagine a 5-line code for the text-style been re-used in 30 different places, just because there's a tiny bit of change in the colour in those cases; that would be a whooping 110+ additional lines of code.
Another reason is to avoid inconsistency and promote code maintenance in your code. Imagine, checking through the UI Designs you realised the text-size should be 24px not 22px, you's need to go through each of those 30 different files or points to fix it manually; and trust me that can get very troublesome.
Lastly, although creating modular codes in this way saves one a lot of hassle; it is completely impractical and redundant to do that for a particular code-snippet you are completely sure will be used once. The key is to be smart about it.

As the other answer suggested, don't stress about it, it is NOT a big performance issue this will cause especially if your application is not that big
As a work around I will suggest this type of arrangement, yes it might create a bunch more of boilerplate but if you want to squeeze that last bit of performance you can take such a tradeoff
static const TextStyle defaultStyle =
 TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
    letterSpacing: 0,
  );

static const TextStyle display1 = 
  TextStyle(
    color: AppColors.black900,
    letterSpacing: defaultStyle.letterSpacing,
    fontFamily: defaultStyle.fontFamily,
    fontSize: 57.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
  );



